# How many $(x,y)$ satisfy this?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How many pairs $(x,y)$ of positive integers

with $x\leq y$ such that

$GCD(x,y) = 5!$ and  $LCM(x,y) = 50! $ ??

Comment: And $x,y \in\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: x,y ∈ positive integers

Comment: The word "couple" is hardly ever used in English-language mathematics as far as I've ever encountered. "Pair" and "ordered pair" are often used, but I can't recall ever seeing "couple." @julien

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  find the prime factorization of $50!$.  For each prime, one of $x,y$ must have the number of factors of $5!$ and one must have the number of factors of $50!$

Comment: can you show the way for solving it? 
Thank you

Comment: I was hoping someone would come up with an argument not involving the prime factorization of $50!$... How do you obtain it  explicitly in a reasonable time without a computer?

Comment: @julien:  The prime factorization of $50!$ is accessible-no prime is greater than $47$.  You can even do it by hand-the number of factors of $2$ is $\lfloor \frac {50}2 \rfloor + \lfloor \frac {50}{2^2} \rfloor +\lfloor \frac {50}{2^3} \rfloor +\lfloor \frac {50}{2^4} \rfloor +\lfloor \frac {50}{2^5} \rfloor=25+12+6+3+1=47$ and other primes are easier.

Comment: @jamesfrouch:  think about the same question for $24=2^3\cdot 3$ and $18=2\cdot 3^2$  To have the proper GCD, both $x,y$ have to have $6=2 \cdot 3$ as a factor and one must have a factor of $2^3$ and one (maybe the same, maybe not) must have a factor of $3^2$

Comment: This is a beautiful formula I had completely forgotten...Thanks, +1.

Comment: @julien:  the magic formula is $GCD(a,b)*LCM(a,b)=a*b$

Comment: That's indeed a great one. I have never forgotten it, unlike the other one.